# Уменьшить анимацию в два раза

Tags: javascript, html, css

Как сделать чтобы сова была в 2 раза меньше?Нужно чтобы только сова стала в 2 раза меньше а все остальные элементы оставались без изменения

https://codepen.io/sasste/pen/MKBJYP

```css
body{
  background: #81d4fa
}

#wind{
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -150px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -150px;
  animation: fly-up-down 8s infinite linear;
}

#bird{
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -150px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -150px;
  animation: fly-rotate 8s infinite linear;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#body{
  position: relative;
  width: 60px;
  height: 50px;
  border-bottom: solid 10px #fff;
  border-right: solid 5px #8B5A2B;
  border-left: solid 5px #8B5A2B;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -30px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -35px;
  background: #8B5A2B;
  border-radius: 28px;
}

#head{
  position: relative;
  width: 40px;
  height: 30px;
  border-top: solid 4px #000;
  border-bottom: solid 8px #df9e6f;
  border-left: solid 4px #df9e6f;
  border-right: solid 4px #df9e6f;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -60px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -24px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 100%;
  animation: updown 7s infinite linear
}

#left-wing{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -15px;
  right: 50%;
  margin-right: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border-top: solid 10px #8B5A2B;
  border-bottom: solid 15px transparent;
  border-right: solid 150px #fff;
  border-left: solid 15px;
  animation: l-wing 1.5s infinite linear;
}

#right-wing{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -15px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border-top: solid 10px #8B5A2B;
  border-bottom: solid 15px transparent;
  border-left: solid 150px #fff;
  border-right: solid 15px; 
  animation: r-wing 1.5s infinite linear;
}

#tail{
  position: absolute;
  width: 24px;
  height: 0px;
  background: #8B5A2B;
  border-bottom: solid 10px #000;
  border-left: solid 20px transparent;
  border-right: solid 20px transparent;
  border-radius: 100px;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: 20px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -33px;
  animation: updown 2s infinite linear;
}

#beak{
  position: absolute;
  border-top: solid 22px #CD661D;
  border-left: solid 10px transparent;
  border-right: solid 10px transparent;
  border-radius: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -10px;
}

.beak-holes{
  position: absolute;
  color: #9a330a;
  width:3px;
  height: 1px;
  background: black;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -17px;  
}

#bh1{
  left: 50%;
  margin-left:-4px;
}

#bh2{
  right: 50%;
  margin-right:-4px;
}

#left-foot{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: 23px;
  right: 50%;
  margin-right: 5px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  border-bottom: solid 10px #CD661D;
  border-left: solid 10px transparent;
  border-right: solid 10px transparent;
}

#right-foot{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: 23px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: 5px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  border-bottom: solid 10px #CD661D;
  border-left: solid 10px transparent;
  border-right: solid 10px transparent;
}

#left-eye{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -5px;
  right: 50%;
  margin-right: 3px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  width: 3px;
  height: 3px;
  background: #fff;
  border-top: solid 1px #000;
  border-bottom: solid 2.5px #000;
  border-left: solid 2.5px #000;
  border-right: solid 2.5px #000;
}

#right-eye{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -5px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: 3px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  width: 3px;
  height: 3px;
  background: #fff;
  border-top: solid 1px #000;
  border-bottom: solid 2.5px #000;
  border-left: solid 2.5px #000;
  border-right: solid 2.5px #000;
}

@keyframes fly-rotate{
  0%{
    -webkit-transform: rotate(10deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(10deg);
    }
  25%{
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-10deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-10deg);
    }
  50%{
    -webkit-transform: rotate(10deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(10deg);
    }
  75%{
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-10deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-10deg);
    }
  100%{
    -webkit-transform: rotate(10deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(10deg);
    }
}

@keyframes fly-up-down{
  
  25%{
    -webkit-transform: translatey(-20px);
    -moz-transform: translatey(-20px)
    }
  50%{
    -webkit-transform: translatey(20px);
    -mozansform: translatey(20px);
    }
  75%{
    -webkit-transform: translatey(-20px);
    -mozansform: translatey(-20px);
    }
}


@keyframes r-wing{
 
  0%{
  margin-top: -5px;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  border-top: solid 10px #8B5A2B;
  border-bottom: solid 15px transparent;
    }
  
  25%{
  margin-top: -25px;
  transform: rotate(-10deg);
  border-top: solid 20px #8B5A2B;
  border-bottom: solid 10px transparent;
    }
  50%{
  margin-top: -5px;
  transform: rotate(10deg);
  border-top: solid 10px #8B5A2B;
  border-bottom: solid 15px transparent;
    }
  75%{
  margin-top: -25px;
  transform: rotate(-10deg);
  border-top: solid 20px #8B5A2B;
  border-bottom: solid 10px transparent;
    }
  
  100%{
  margin-top: -5px;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  border-top: solid 10px #8B5A2B;
  border-bottom: solid 15px transparent;
    }
}

@keyframes l-wing{

  0%{
  margin-top: -5px;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  border-top: solid 10px #8B5A2B;
  border-bottom: solid 15px transparent;
    }
  
  25%{
  margin-top: -25px;
  transform: rotate(10deg);
  border-top: solid 20px #8B5A2B;
  border-bottom: solid 10px transparent;
    }
  50%{
  margin-top: -5px;
  transform: rotate(-10deg);
  border-top: solid 10px #8B5A2B;
  border-bottom: solid 15px transparent;
    }
  75%{
  margin-top: -25px;
  transform: rotate(10deg);
  border-top: solid 20px #8B5A2B;
  border-bottom: solid 10px transparent;
    }
  
  100%{
  margin-top: -5px;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  border-top: solid 10px #8B5A2B;
  border-bottom: solid 15px transparent;
    }
}

@keyframes updown{
   0%{
  transition-duration: 5s;
  transform: translatey(-2px);
    }
  25%{
  transition-duration: 5s;
  transform: translatey(4px);
    }
  50%{
  transition-duration: 5s;  
  transform: translatey(0px);
    }
  75%{
  transition-duration: 5s;
  transform: translatey(4px);
    }
  100%{
  transition-duration: 5s;
  transform: translatey(-2px);
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="wind">

  <div id="bird">

    <div id="tail">
    </div>

    <div id="left-wing">
    </div>

    <div id="right-wing">
    </div>

    <div id="left-foot">
    </div>

    <div id="right-foot">
    </div>

    <div id="body">
    </div>

    <div id="head">

      <div id="left-eye">
      </div>

      <div id="right-eye">
      </div>

      <div id="beak">
        <div id="bh1" class="beak-holes">
          </div>
        <div id="bh2" class="beak-holes">
          </div>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Тут получается что как бы все элементы и всё полотно уменьшается в 2 раза.А как сделать чтобы только сова уменьшалась а остальные элементы оставались такими же?

Comment: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/VNyqOe - так ?

Comment: Идеально,если хотите можете оформить как ответ дам лучшего

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В приведённой вёрстке очень много элементов и что бы не парится с уменьшением и расчётом слоёв мы обернём весь этот контейнер в другой блок и уже его уменьшим  таким способом :

.item{transform:scale(0.5)translate(0,500px)}

И обязательно разместим в самом низу css файла  что бы избежать многих не приятностей

Разумеется что цифры с головы и для реального проекта надо дорабатывать

Comment: спасибо большое